# magento 2 : model in custom module

Tags: magento2, model, resource-model

> i already have a **table** in **database** also created **model** **files** and all works fine so now added **another** **table** successfully so what **changes** i need to do with **model** **files**

i mean in **model** **resourcemodel** and **connection** files..

Comment: Have you got solution? or you have any concern.

Comment: yes got it ...now works

Comment: If you happy with the solution then you can accept as a answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tirth Patel
I think you should create separate model as well as Resource file for another db table.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add another resource modal connection **(CRUD)**

**Step : 1 Create Model**

> app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/Model/Post.php

**Step : 2 Create Resource Model**

> app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/Post.php

**Step : 3 Create Resource Model Collection - Get Model Collection**

> app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/Post/Collection.php

After this please run this command line:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento C:F

Answer (score 1):

do same process for your second table what you have done for your first table. i mean `create diffrent model,resource file` for your second table.